# Automatic rewrite on URLs

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I am having an issue with my website as it keeps changing the urls and adding some unusual things at the end of it.

Example: http://website.com/page

turns into

Example: http://website.com/page#.UMELy-OLLaU

How can i fix this? or where should i be looking to get more information. The htaccess is a normal drupal htaccess.

http://puragen.co.uk

Thanks for the help.
Kind Regards

Comment: Please post your code here, I don't want to go to your site.

Comment: What code would you like? its a whole drupal website...

Comment: I assumed since you put the jQuery and HTML tags on there, that was your issue. Post the offending jQuery code.

Comment: Nope, it just happens. http://puragen.co.uk/sites/default/files/js/js_bbac74a5285ed7005c624af9cbca71f5.js here is the javascript file. Since i started the website, this has happened. I thought it might be a rewrite issue but nothing in the logs that explains this

Comment: Have you tried the same site in another browser/computer to rule out extensions interfering with your URLs on the client side?

Comment: Yep, nearly 10 different computers and Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari, Opera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment is being added by the **AddThis** javascript (addthis_widget.js). It's what you are apparently using for the share buttons on each of your pages. The script creates an ID for your site and adds it as a fragment. I *think* you can get rid of it by configuring the AddThis widget, but I've never done it personally. If that doesn't work, you can try configuring it inside your header by adding this to the overall page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var addthis_config = {
      "data_track_addressbar" : false
   };
</script>
```

Comment: Ah thank you soo much! didnt know addthis was an issue! worked like a charm